# Import function is not working and throwing a 404

Tags: javascript, json, request, httprequest

I am working on a Nano (cryptocurrency) faucet, and I am using [this](https://github.com/numsu/nanocurrency-web-js) JS extension to handle the wallets and transactions. I have my Javascript file in my HTML file with `type='module'`, and this:

```
import { wallet } from '/node_modules/nanocurrency-web/dist/index.js';
const abc = wallet.generate();
window.alert(abc.mnemonic);
```

in my JS file. When I open the page, I get this error in the console:

```
GET https://earnnano.github.io/node_modules/nanocurrency-web/dist/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

I'm not sure what is wrong, but any help would be great! Thanks! :3

Comment: try `import { wallet } from 'nanocurrency-web'`

Comment: @CHANist I tried that, and got this message: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "nanocurrency-web". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: @CHANist and when I tried putting a / at the beginning, it gave this error again: GET https://earnnano.github.io/nanocurrency-web net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: have you run npm init? Why it does not have package.json file?